# Rails Ajax Refresh Partial while persisting params

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app with a controller/view called "calls".  Here is the basic controller action for index:

**calls_controller.rb**

```
def index
    if params[:region].present?
      @assigned = Call.where(region_id: params[:region][:area]).assigned_calls.until_end_of_day
      @unassigned = Call.where(region_id: params[:region][:area]).unassigned_calls.until_end_of_day
   else
     @assigned = Call.assigned_calls.until_end_of_day
     @unassigned = Call.unassigned_calls.until_end_of_day
   end
  end
```

Here are my views:

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#active').html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'calls/assigned_calls', :locals => {:assigned_calls => @assigned} %>");
$('#inactive').html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'calls/unassigned_calls', :locals => {:unassigned_calls => @unassigned} %>"); 

$(".select").select2({
        placeholder: "Select One",
        allowClear: true
  });
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="active">
  <%= render "assigned_calls" %>
</div>

<div id="inactive">
  <%= render "unassigned_calls" %>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax('calls/<%= params[:region][:area] %>');
    } , 5000);
});
</script>
```

**_assigned_calls.html.erb (view code omitted)**

```
<%= form_tag calls_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
<%= select_tag "region[area]", options_from_collection_for_select(Region.order(:area), :id, :area, selected: params[:region].try(:[], :area)), prompt: "Choose Region" %>
<%= submit_tag "Select", :name => nil, :class => 'btn' %>
```

So what's happening is on page load if I do not have the params of :region passed it sets the calls without being scoped by region.  If region_id is present then it scopes calls where region_id is "1" or whatever the Region ID is that is passed from the submit_tag.

This works fine in the controller and view, however here's my problem.  My index.html.erb I need to refresh the partials WITHOUT disturbing the params passed.  So on setInterval I need to figure out how to reload the partials while persisting the params passed in the URL.

I tried to figure this out using a setInterval method but I'm not sure what I'm doing here 100%.

Can someone give me some advice on how to refresh the partials every 5 seconds while persisting the params so my instance variables persist through refresh?

If you need more context and/or code please let me know.

**Update**
Trying to rework the javascript based off an answer from a user and here's what I have.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'calls_path',
        type: "GET",
        data: { "region": '<%= @region.html_safe %>' }
      }), 5000);
    });
  });
</script>
```

The page will load but when it tried to trigger in the chrome inspector I get:

```
calls?utf8=✓&region[area]=3:2901 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Maybe this is a JS syntax error or I'm not closing the function properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly, you want to have your parameters somehow pipelined through AJAX call to your controller, back to your `js.erb` file where it refreshes the partials?

My advice is to set passed parameters as instance variables in your controller like this:

**calls_controller.rb**

```
def index
  if params[:region].present?
    @region = params[:region]

    @assigned = Call.where(region_id: params[:region][:area]).assigned_calls.until_end_of_day
    @unassigned = Call.where(region_id: params[:region][:area]).unassigned_calls.until_end_of_day
  else
    @assigned = Call.assigned_calls.until_end_of_day
    @unassigned = Call.unassigned_calls.until_end_of_day
  end
end
```

Now your `@region` instance variable will be available in your `index.js.erb`
where you can pass it to other partials you are trying to render.

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#active').html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'calls/assigned_calls', :locals => { :assigned_calls => @assigned, :region => @region } %>");
$('#inactive').html("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'calls/unassigned_calls', :locals => { :unassigned_calls => @unassigned, :region => @region } %>");
```

**_assigned_calls.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag calls_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= select_tag "region[area]", options_from_collection_for_select(Region.order(:area), :id, :area, selected: region.try(:[], :area)), prompt: "Choose Region" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Select", :name => nil, :class => 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

Also, I think that better practice in your `index.html.erb` script tag
is to do it like this:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     setInterval(function () {
       $.ajax({
         url: 'calls_path',
         type: "GET",
         data: { "region": '<%= @region.html_safe %>' }
       });
     }, 5000);
   });
</script>
```

Please test this out if you're interested and get back to me :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I cut/pasted this in and I'm getting `undefined local variable or method `region'` on line 5 of _assigned_calls.html.erb Here's the offending line: `  <%= select_tag "region[area]", options_from_collection_for_select(Region.order(:area), :id, :area, selected: region.try(:[], :area)), prompt: "Choose Region" %>
`  Any thoughts?

Comment: I can get rid of that error by changing line 5 to <%= select_tag "region[area]", options_from_collection_for_select(Region.order(:area), :id, :area, selected: params[:region].try(:[], :area)), prompt: "Choose Region" %> using the params[:region] instead of the local variable region.  Not sure why it's not hooking up properly.

Comment: When I do use the params in my option_from_collection_for_select it works fine, but the javascript gives "calls?utf8=✓&region[area]=4:6387 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" from the index.html.erb.

Comment: Here's the code I'm using based off what you supplied. <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'calls_path',
        type: "GET",
        data: { "region": '<%= @region %>' }
      }), 5000);
    });
  });
</script>

Comment: Maybe try in your `script` tag to use `data: { '<%= @region.html_safe %>' } %>` instead of `data: { '<%= @region %>' } %>`

Tell me if this works so I can edit my answer. @shakycode

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried the .html_safe and I still get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ).  Any other thoughts or ideas?  I think this could be a syntax error in my script.  I'll show my current script and update my question.

Comment: Can you try `data: { region: '<%= j @region %>' }` and tell me what you get?

Also I don't know why `region` is undefined in your partial when rendering it through `index.js.erb`. One more question, did you post your full `index` action from the controller?

Comment: Hi Nikola.  The index action is complete in my original question, yes.  I tried your suggestion data: { region: '<%= j @region %>' } and it does not work, in the console (chrome inspector) I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ).  I'm confused now :)

Comment: OK, I'm confident this will not throw SyntaxError, I'll update my answer.

Problem was with the extra `)` in your script tag.

Comment: @shakycode I've updated my answer, hopefully this javascript will work. Can you please try it out? :)

Comment: Nope, unfortunately still stuck on this one. :(

Comment: @shakycode What's the error now? Have you taken a look at my updated answer, you should not have syntax errors anymore.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `region' for #<#<Class:0x007f96e49751d0>:0x007f96e4e15208> in _assigned_calls.html.erb.  It's complaining bout the select_tag line.

Comment: When is that error occurring? Are you rendering that `_assigned_calls` partial anywhere else? If you are, make sure to pass it `region` variable.

Comment: The _assigned_calls partial is not rendered anywhere else.  And the region variable is getting passed through the local.  But I still get the undefined local var for class.  So I tried altering the select tag to <%= select_tag "region[area]", options_from_collection_for_select(Region.order(:area), :id, :area, selected: @region.try(:[], :area)), prompt: "Choose Region" %> but get can't convert symbol into integer

Comment: @Nikola Đuza this was very useful!

Comment: @KavitaC Thank you, I'm glad I helped :)